# source command does not take effect

Tags: python, linux, paramiko

I have a cluster of machines, and I write a Python script to change the hostname; the code follows.

What puzzles me is that the **`source` command only takes effect on some machines, not all**.  After I repeat several times, then all hostname take effect [BTW: I can change the hostname in `/etc/hostname`, but the hostname service do not take effect.]

```
import paramiko
import time
import threading
import os

cmd0 = "sudo source /root/.bashrc"
cmd1 = "sudo service hostname stop"
cmd2 = "sudo service hostname start"

def executeit(ip):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh.connect(ip, 22, "root")
    ssh.exec_command(cmd0)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd1)
    out = stdout.readlines()
    for o in out:
            print(o)
    time.sleep(1)
    ssh.exec_command(cmd2) 
    ssh.close()

    print("=======")

def main():
        fr = open("info.txt", "r")
        contents = fr.read().splitlines()
        fr.close()
        for ip in contents:
                t = threading.Thread(target=executeit, args=(ip,))
                t.start()

main()
```

Comment: Are you sure the default shell on all machines in bash? `source` only works in bash; and should be avoided.

Comment: You don't use `source` in your code, which makes the question unclear.  Also, you don't need `sudo` since you ssh as `root`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  all my machine is ubuntu12.04 server edition.

Comment: @JohnZwinck oh,it is my mistake, i write server scripts. both the source /etc/.bashrc command do not take effect on all the machine, also the sudo service hostname take effect on all machine. I have correct my answer.

Comment: You should be able to just do `service hostname restart`.  No stop/start, no "source bashrc", no "sudo."  Keep it simple.

Comment: Why I use the stop/start, it because when i used the restart command ,it seem do not work[i do this when i login the server, and manual do this, not in the python script].
i do not confirm if this is the sudo problem. maybe i can try it.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned this here: if you run `sudo source /some/script` it doesn't do what you might expect -- while any commands in the script are of course run, you will not be able to take advantage of any variables set up by the script since it only affects the environment set up by `sudo`.

Comment: @larsks but I do some operations as the root then, does it also not change the environment?

Comment: I think your problem is that the `source` operation in `cmd0` affects that shell, but doesn't affect the environment of the separate shell that runs `cmd1` or the one that runs `cmd2`.  You should probably run a single command: `cmd = "sudo bash -c 'source /root/.bashrc; service hostname stop; service hostname start'"` or thereabouts.  Does the `service` command provide a `restart` option?

Comment: @Djvu As far as I remember, the default shell on ubuntu 12.04 is indeed not bash but dash, or rather `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/dash`, which was very annoying. Further I wonder why you think you need /etc/.bashrc just to run `service hostname start`.